# Endless loop while using Angularjs with laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, angular-routing

I have problem when using ngRoute with laravel.

routes.php:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return File::get(public_path() . '/angular.html');
});
```

here's my angular.html (this is where i use `ng-view`):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular & Laravel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Angular, hello!</h2>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
// define app

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// routes

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/posts', {
        templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
        controller: 'firstCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

// controllers

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope)
{
   $scope.name = 'Ebosher';
});

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('/api/posts').then(function(result) {
        $scope.posts = result.data;
    });
});
```

Now, when i visit http//project.local - my browser hangs because of endless loops - it keeps repeating the same text endless times. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The angular looks okay. It looks like you are using a 404 handler (App::missing()) to serve your angular. You really REALLY shouldn't do this (you can see why right now). Remove that handler (or make it an actual 404 handler), then just create a view with the angular in it and `return View::make('angular.html');` from inside your controller or your route's closure.

What is happening is this: Your app loads and can't find a proper route. App redirects you the way it would for a 404. Angular loads up and calls ./api/posts which results in a 404.... which loads angular again...